# How to order your result in a specific way in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a simple query, but I would like to see the results in a specific way. I would like to see 'N/A' at the top of the result, without having to result to "Case When Then"

```
Select  *
From Ordertype
```

Results:

```
Car21
Car34
Bus42
N/A
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you share some more information like  your table design!!

Comment: Do you have a key associated with the values that you can order on? By the way, why cant you use "Case When Then" ?

Comment: How are you expecting that result to be consistent even now, when you don't have an `ORDER BY` at all? Repeat after me: a table is a bag of rows. When you select from a table, it could come out in any order, unless you specify an order using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Show the rest of the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an arbitrary order that is not tied directly to the structured of a column (alphabetical/numerical) but rather to it's importance which only you know in your head it can be useful to add a `Rank` column to your table.

```
Column1 Rank
Car21   
Car34   2
Bus42   1
N/A     99
```

then you can do

```
select Column1 
from Table 
order by rank desc, column1
```

This will put highly ranked items first then low ranked items, then when rows don't have a rank it will sort them alphabetically by column1

Answer (score 2):

There are no 'overrides' for `ORDER BY`, if you want the specific order you're asking for, you'll have to use the `CASE`:

```
SELECT type
FROM OrderType
ORDER BY 
 CASE
    WHEN type = 'N/A' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
 END 
,type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ordertype ORDER BY ID DESC
```

to see the newest ones 1st